# Trying to save a pdf file of a screenshot of the form, given a specified location from the user's input

Tags: vb.net, pdfsharp

I am trying to save a created, PDF file to a location specified by the user. I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019. Essentially, I am taking a screenshot of this form:

[image]

And by using the PdfSharp external library, I create a PDF file and then save that PDF to some file location specified by the user. Here is the UI for the user to select their preferred file location:

[image]

The **issue** arises once the program tries to save the PDF file to the location given by the user. Here is the error I get from Visual Studio:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'No data is available for encoding 1252. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.'

I looked online for this specific error, but I don't really understand it nor what to do with it, it's very confusing. I'm still a bit of beginner when it comes to working with Visual Basic. Here's the code that tries to do it:

```
    Dim fileLocation As String

    fileLocation = folderBrowseBox.Text

    GetFormImage(True).Save(fileLocation & "\" & RemoveWhitespace(filename) & "_" & RemoveWhitespace(collectionPeriod) & ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)

    ' Create new pdf document and page
    Dim doc As New PdfDocument()
    Dim oPage As New PdfPage()

    ' Add the page to the pdf document and add the captured image to it
    doc.Pages.Add(oPage)
    Dim img As XImage = XImage.FromFile(fileLocation & "\" & RemoveWhitespace(filename) & "_" & RemoveWhitespace(collectionPeriod) & ".jpg")

    'Create XImage object from file.
    Using xImg = PdfSharp.Drawing.XImage.FromFile(fileLocation & "\" & RemoveWhitespace(filename) & "_" & RemoveWhitespace(collectionPeriod) & ".jpg")
        'Resize page Width and Height to fit image size.
        oPage.Width = xImg.PixelWidth * 72 / xImg.HorizontalResolution
        oPage.Height = xImg.PixelHeight * 72 / xImg.HorizontalResolution

        'Draw current image file to page.
        Dim xgr = PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics.FromPdfPage(oPage)
        xgr.DrawImage(xImg, 0, 0, oPage.Width, oPage.Height)
    End Using

    doc.Save(fileLocation & "\" & RemoveWhitespace(filename) & "_" & RemoveWhitespace(collectionPeriod))

    img.Dispose()
```

The second to last line of code ("**doc.Save(fileLocation & ...)**") is where the error occurs. The **folderBrowseBox.Text** (very first line of code) comes from the textbox you see from my second screenshot. Any help/advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where are `RemoveWhitespace()`, `filename` and `collectionPeriod` defined?

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville `RemoveWhitespace()` is a function I made that is outside the code you see from my post above. Essentially all the code you see from my post takes place when the user clicks on the button "2) Create PDF". I didn't include that part of the because I worried my post would be too long/boring, and I wanted to get to the point. `filename` and `collectionPeriod` are variables I declared as strings within the "2) Create PDF" button click event; they are set as the input from the textboxes found next to "Company/Client name" and "Collection Period" from the first screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding this line before writing the PDF file

`System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance)`

Got the idea from [here](https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp/issues/66#issuecomment-493719568)